# How to create locators that are arrays globally

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I created `@{some_locator}=  Get WebElements  css=article[id^='hello'] a`

and it works. It gets all of the a's and stores them in an array; however, when I initialize this array in the variable section like this, it does not work. It does not create an array

```
**Variables**

@{some_locator}  css=article[id^='hello'] a
```

Please Note: The variable is created in a separate file.

Comment: The two pieces of code are different, why do you expect them to behave the same?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In the first block `@{some_locator}=  Get webelements ...`, you are calling a keyword that returns a list of web elements.

In the second, you are creating an array and giving it a string as the only element. It should still be an array, but it will be an array with a single string.

If you are wanting to use this locator later you'll need to use array syntax to get the locator out of the list of locators:

```
Get WebElements  ${some_locator[0]}
```

If you don't want `some_locator` to be a list with one element, you can do it like this:

```
*** Variables ***
${some_locator}  css=article[id^='hello'] a

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    @{elements}=  Get webelements  ${some_locator}
```